# JMX authorize by method name using a java policy file

Tags: authorization, jmx, javapolicy

Can I write a java policy file to authorize with readOnly or readWrite access for individual methods (by the method name) of an Mbean server for JMX monitoring? If yes, please show an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here may be useful: http://www.journaldev.com/1359/java-jmx-client-example-authentication

Comment: @BladeMight Thanks for the link. It shows the authorization with default access and password files which grants readOnly or readWrite to all methods. But I want to make it fine-grained by granting permissions to individual methods using a java policy file in specific. Any assistance on this is much appreciated.